# Google Custom Search API javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, google-custom-search

I'm writing an AngularJS application which should perform image search through entire web using google custom search api. 
I've used the query as follows:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='+ googleApiKey + '&cx=014766414461901118935:knbecyxzx4u&searchType=image&startIndex=41&imgType=photo&q=' + query;
```

As a result I get an array which consists of 10 elements. The documentation says that it can return up to the first 100 results. How can I load all the rest of results beside those 10 which come from the query above?

Note: Besides the array of images I also get the query object which has the `nextPage` object which holds the metadata describing the query to use for the next page of results, but apparently I have no idea how to use it as the `startIndex` value is always `11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you use `&start` instead of `&startIndex`